# std::random_shuffle, compiler error: no matching function for call

Tags: c++, gcc, stl

I cannot compile following code by g++ 4.3.2:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <algorithm>

struct Generator {
  ptrdiff_t operator() (ptrdiff_t max) {
    return rand() % max;
  }
};

Generator generator;
std::vector<size_t> indices;
// fill vector
std::random_shuffle(indices.begin(), indices.end(), generator); // error here!
```

Why my compiler throws following error in last line?

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘random_shuffle(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >, Generator&)’
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If I understand correctly your answer below, the example code you've provided above actually compiles successfully, and the code that generates the error is different.  Please understand why that's an incredibly unhelpful way to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

Actually in my code `Generator` structure is declared within a function. I don't know wjy, but g++ 4.3.2 does not accept this. After I moved structure declaration out of function, compilation successes. I believe this is a bug in compiler. Moreover original code was successfully compiled by earlier version of g++.

Comment: You cannot instantiate a template with a local type.  `random_shuffle` is a class template, and `Generator` is a local type.  This is why it works if you move `Generator` so that it is not a local type.